# Search in the combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a project in which I want that when I Press 'a' in combobox the words corresponding which is start From 'a' are show into the combobox.

Comment: What technology are you using - WinForms, WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for the autofilter combobox.
[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/11/12/5088649.aspx),
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e52796d1-d58a-438b-aba1-59844d24f419)
and [here](http://dotbay.blogspot.de/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html)